# Visual Studio Shell 2010 OLE DB Connection Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

A very weird error emerged when using SV 2010. This error came immediately after installing the SSDT 2015in my machine. The error pops up whenever I use the OLE DB Source task! I have seen an answer about this issue but it was for 2012 version. Any help would be very appreciated!

Error:

> Method not found: 'Void
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.DataFlowConnectionPage.set_DataPreviewTimeout(Int32)'.
>   (Microsoft Visual Studio)

Comment: some dll missing or registry have issue  try reinstall  ssdt...

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your comment. The dll are corrupted in the SSIS 2010 I guess!! Why do I need to reinstall the SSDT15 instead??